# Making the contents of a Sub Directory appear more prominent

Tags: url, subdirectory

Lets assume that you own a number of zines or small blogs that are all different in theme, and all rest on seperate domains:

`http://example-one.com` . `http://example-two.com` . `http://example-three.com`

Visitors to these sites would assume they are all completely independent of each other, and that none are related (unless you specified it).

But lets assume that you own a single domain and place each blog inside of a dedicated sub-directory:

`http://example.com/x/one` . `http://example.com/x/two` . `http://example.com/x/three`

In this case, `/x/` is a really a sort of fake directory, containing an index page that automatically redirects back to example.com.

Now the problem is that visitors to the site will make the assumption that you own more than one blog, and doing a search for example.com/x may result in them finding the contents of your other online blogs.

So, without registering multiple domains, is there a way to make it appear that the blog a visitor is looking at is the only one you own?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! People will commonly separate different subjects using a sub-domain so that they do not dilute search value. Using directories within a single site can potentially dilute search value. However, you seem to be asking how to have one site act as three sites, which a sub-domain would do, however, it sounds like you really want three domains without paying for and registering them. If this is the case, the answer is No. It is possible to have one site answer to several domain names and serve the correctly content for each, however, this can be tricky. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

As @closetnoc said above, no, you can't make it appear as if you only have one blog when they're all subfolders on the same top level domain, at least as far as search engines are concerned. Assuming that you want your TLD as well as each of these blogs in the search indexes, you'll have to let all of this be crawled and indexed. Thus, anyone doing any in-depth search - or stumbling on it in SERPs accidentally - may well come across this and connect the dots. (And in terms of masking your subdirectory's full path, I'm not sure, but careful that you don't damage your SEO game.)

However, visually you should be able to separate your various subdirectories by using different themes/CSS for different folders, so that at least if someone hits two of your blogs, they'll look completely different. WordPress [has a plugin](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-use-multiple-themes-for-pages-in-wordpress/) for it, and I believe Drupal has something similar (not sure if it's a module, but I've seen it done). Depending on your CMS, you may need to check the documentation, or call customer support, to find out how or if this can be executed.